# Kotlin Convert Double to Long using A Swift TimeStamp

Tags: swift, kotlin, double, long-integer

When sending a Swift timeStamp to FirebaseRTDB I use a `Double` (seconds):

```
let timeStamp = Date().timeIntevalSince1970 // eg 1633598017.489507
```

When reading the value on an iOS device I use

```
let timeStamp = dict["timeStamp"] as? Double
if let timeStamp = timeStamp {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStamp)
}
```

When using Kotlin to send a timeStamp to FirebaseRTDB I use `Long` (milliseconds)

```
let timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() // eg 1689308567775
```

When reading the value on an Android device I use

```
let timeStamp = map["timeStamp"] as? Long
if (timeStamp != null) {
    let date = Date(timeStamp)
}
```

The issue that I ran into is they share the same database. The iOS part was built first and the db already has timeStamp values as Doubles. What I need to do is when on an Android device and I get an iOS timeStamp, I need to convert it from a Double to a Long so that I can use it in a Date() object.

```
val timeStamp = map["timeStamp"] as? Long // if this isn't null, it came from an Android device. If it is null, it came from an iOS device
if (timeStamp != null) {

    let date = Date(timeStamp) // eg timeStamp is 1689308567775

} else {

    val iOSTimeStamp = dict["timeStamp"] as? Double // eg timeStamp is 1633598017.489507
    val convertedTimeStamp = // convert iOSTimeStamp to a Long ...

    let date = Date(convertedTimeStamp)
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: I've been trying different Android answers to convert `iOSTimeStamp` from a Double to a Long but I haven't been able to get right.

Comment: So you're looking for [`roundToLong`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/round-to-long.html) or [`toLong`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-double/to-long.html)?

Comment: It worked, thanks. I needed to first multiply `iOSTimeStamp * 1000` then use what you gave me. Thanks. If you post them as an answer I'll accept. You probably have to put in there about the multiplication though.